# Implement async/await angular 7

Tags: angular, typescript

Can someone please help me implement async/await for this angular/typescript method

```js
onCustomerSelected(cId) {
    let cust = this.custlist.find((c) => c.custId == cId);

    this.service.setCustomer(cust); //need to await this method (note, this doesnt return promise)

    ... do some processing ...
    (note, i need to wait for the service to set customer first, before i can begin further processing)   
}
```

Comment: Check this https://medium.com/@pavankjadda/synchronous-http-calls-in-angular-7-using-async-and-await-d0af7910f6d7

Comment: async/await are literally made to handle asynchronous code without using callbacks, can you please pinpoint where exactly is the asynchronous part of you code ?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming `this.service.setCustomer` returns a `Promise`, you just need to flag the function `onCustomerSelected` as `async` and then `await` `this.serice.setCustomer`

```
async onCustomerSelected(cId) {
    let cust = this.custlist.find((c) => c.custId == cId);

    await this.service.setCustomer(cust); //need to await this method (note, this doesnt return promise)

}
```

If `this.service.setCustomer` is an `Observable`, then you need to do `await this.service.setCustomer(...).toPromise();`

Comment: the setCustomer neither returns a promise or is an observable. how can i achieve in that case?

Comment: Make it return a promise or an observable. Or, you can of course wrap the function into a promise or an observable.

Comment: If you add the code `setCustomer` I can get a better idea of what it does and how you could go about it.

Comment: This is the code for setCustomer. It is an async but doesnt return promise or observable

public async setCustomer (cId: any) {
  ...
  ...
}

Comment: If it's async then you can just await it.

Answer (score 1):

You need to wrap your service call in a Promise and use await with it.

`const result = await this.service.setCustomer(cust).toPromise()`

Comment: I am unable to do that since setCustomer does not return a promise. Is there any other way?

Comment: you have called "toPromise()" with the service?